# Android: Mediarecoder is throwing IllegalStateException in start()

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I want to use the `mediarecorder` in my app to record voice.
I do exactly what is described under http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html but the `exception` is always thrown in the `start()` method.
The code should be fine, as I also tried out the code example called `Mediarecorder` from google but I get the same `exception:`

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
    mRecorder.start();
```

I have already added the permissions (`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`) to the `AndroidManifest.xml,` and I start the app on my connected smartphone.

Does anybody know what might cause the `Exception` and what one has to do?

Comment: Study the life cycle of MediaRecorder.

Comment: provide the logs showing the illegal state exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I was able to resolve the issue. I had in fact a missing mRecorder.release() and so it seems that the start method was called twice.